# Como executar o evento de click em uma imagem que está no fragment da activity?

Tags: android

Eu quero executar a função que está fragment - remover tarefa() - em uma imagem que está no fragment sendo adicionado na activity em tempo de execução, e não estou conseguindo, me ajudem !!!

Código da activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView botao_deletar;
public static SQLiteDatabase banco_dados;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

Código do fragment

```
public class ListaNotificacoes extends Fragment {

View minha_view;


private ListView lista_notify;
private ArrayAdapter<String> itens_adaptador;
private ArrayList<String> itens;
private ArrayList<Integer> ids;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    minha_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_notificacoes, container, false);
    return minha_view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

private void remover_tarefa(Integer id){
    try {
        banco_dados.execSQL("DELETE FROM lista_notificacoes WHERE id="+id);
        recupera_tarefa();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

O que eu tentei fazer...

```
public class ListaNotificacoes extends Fragment {

View minha_view;


private ListView lista_notify;
private ImageView botao_deletar;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    minha_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_notificacoes, container, false);
    return minha_view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    recupera_tarefa();

    botao_deletar = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.botao_deletar);

    botao_deletar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            remover_tarefa(lista_notify.getId());
        }
    });
}

private void remover_tarefa(Integer id){
    try {
        banco_dados.execSQL("DELETE FROM lista_notificacoes WHERE id="+id);
        recupera_tarefa();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

O erro que mostra no console...

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Qual o problema? O que ocorre?

Comment: Eu vou editar a pergunta e vou colocar o que eu tentei fazer pra você poder me ajudar... pera

Comment: A `ImageView` está na activity ou no layout do fragment?

Comment: no layout do fragment

Answer (score 1):

Irei assumir que você não está conseguindo referenciar sua `ImageView` no seu código, ok?

Se eu estiver errado, avise-me. De qualquer maneira, o que você fazer para poder obter a referência do **widget** é utilizar a **minha_view** como identificador.

O método **findViewById()** pode ser chamado de duas formas:

```
View.findViewById()
Activity.findViewById() || Context.findViewById() ~ Context as Activity.
```

Em `fragments`, precisamos passar um `identificador` para que o método possa encontrar a sua `view`, se não passarmos, não vai funcionar, já que você não está em uma activity.

O seu código final ficaria assim:

```
Button deleteTask;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    minha_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_notificacoes, container, false);

    deleteTask = (Button) minha_view.findViewById(R.id.action_delete_task) // mude para o Id do seu componente
    deleteTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            remover_tarefa(taskId);
        }
    });

    return minha_view;
}
```

---

Se você estiver utilizando **Java 8**, você pode utilizar [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) para escrever menos e evitar **boilerplate code**. Seu código ficaria assim:

```
deleteTask = (Button) minha_view.findViewById(R.id.action_delete_task)
deleteTask.setOnClickListener(v -> remover_tarefa(taskId))
```

Para poder utilizar *Lambda Expressions*, você precisa habilitar a compatibilidade com o *Java 8*. Para fazer isso, você precisa modificar o `build.gradle` no nível da aplicação, ou seja, no módulo `app`.

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
    ...
        jackOptions {
           enabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
 }
```

Comment: continuou o mesmo erro, me ajuda !!! não sei o que fazer...

Answer (score 0):

Você está obtendo este erro porque no método `onActivityCreated` do seu fragmento, você está buscando por uma visão na sua atividade, porém ela pertence ao seu fragmento.

[image: Fragment Lifecycle]

Se você analisar o ciclo de vida de um fragmento, o método `onActivityCreated` é executado após o `onCreateView`, o que significa que nele você já possui a visão inflada e já pode utilizar ela.

Apenas mude seu código, e troque `getActivity()` para `getView()`, no método `onActivityCreated` do seu fragmento:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    recupera_tarefa();

    botao_deletar = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.botao_deletar);

    botao_deletar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            remover_tarefa(lista_notify.getId());
        }
    });
}
```

**Nota**: Deve existir de fato uma visão com o id `R.id.botao_deletar` no layout (`R.layout.lista_notificacoes`) que é inflado pelo seu fragmento, para que não seja lançado um **NullPointerException**.

Comment: na sua nota final eu fiquei pensando nisso, por que não tem nenhuma imageview com esse id no layout, mas só que dentro desse layout tem uma listView que está sendo populada com outro layout que possui a imageView com aquele id, será que o problema é esse ?

Comment: Então você deve pegar esse evento no adapter que manipula sua lista. Pode atualizar a pergunta com ele?